# Yeoman Errors, Can't Access Yeoman, Issue: "Error: Cannot find module 'cli-width'"

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm getting errors trying to install yeoman generators. I have previously scaffolded out many projects with yeoman.

I don't know what caused me to get errors, but no yeoman commands work anymore. I can't run `yo`and I can't scaffold a project out or install any new generators.

Here's a little history of my errors

```
$ yo angular

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'through'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/bottom-bar.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Then I installed this 'through' module:

```
npm install -g through
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/apigee-127/node_modules/apigee-remote-proxy/node_modules/inquirer requires lodash@'^3.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/apigee-127/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer requires chalk@'^0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gulp-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer requires lodash@'^3.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-gulp-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.1
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "through"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.6
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.11.1 wants generator-karma@>=0.9.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular-php@0.6.2 wants generator-karma@~0.8.3

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/PersonalProjects/ionicProject/npm-debug.log
```

Ok so it should be all good now right? Wrong,

```
 $ yo
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'cli-width'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/tty.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

I have stopped there, I don't want to go down a worm hole installing npm packages without knowing if I'm on the right path or not. I can't find anything with similar problems so I'm not sure of the root cause that started causing these errors.

I'm on OSX using Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't provide the command you ran, so it's hard to help... But it's definitively an issue with npm.

But two usual trouble shooting:

1. [Never run npm with sudo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md).
2. Read the npm installation log as it may already have told you what the errors were.